# Upper bounds for the set $\lbrace x\in {\mathbb Q}: x^2<2\rbrace$

Tags: upper-lower-bounds, ordered-fields

Consider an ordered field $F$ containing the rational numbers $\mathbb Q$, without assuming the completeness axiom. In particular, this means that the integers may well be bounded. (see this nice example by Tim Gowers: [The unboundedness of the integers](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/%7Ewtg10/meta.integers.html)), so that we cannot use density of the rationals either, as that depends on the Archimedean principle, which is a consequence of the completeness axiom.

Consider now the set $S=\lbrace x\in {\mathbb Q}: x^2<2\rbrace$. In this context, I  would like to see a proof that if $M\in F$ is any upper bound for $S$, then $M^2\geq 2$.

Answer (score 4):

In fact this is false in general! Suppose for example that $F$ is a non-Archimedean extension of $\mathbb{R}$. Then $F$ has an infinitesimal element $\epsilon$, and the element $M=\sqrt{2}-\epsilon$ is an upper bound of your set $S$ (since in the definition of $S$ we only look at rationals) which has $M^2<2$.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I now wonder, is it possible to prove, using only the ordered field axioms for $\mathbb Q$, and without embedding it into $\mathbb R$, that any upper bound for $S$ in $\mathbb Q$ must have $M^2>2$? in other words can we prove that if $M\in {\mathbb Q}$ and $x^2<M$ for all $x$ such that $x^2<2$, then $M^2>2$? It seems to me that it's necessary to use density of the rationals, but that will make use of the completeness axiom.